# In Azure B2C Sign Up Flow, How to warn user email is in use when clicking 'Send Verfication Code' button

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have a B2C sign-up only custom policy, with a custom email display control. Currently, the user is notified AFTER validating the email, that the email is already in use. (profile and password information are collected on a later step)

Here is some relevant code to accomplish this:

```
            <TechnicalProfile Id="PartnerSignUpVerifyEmailPage">
                <DisplayName>Local Email Verification</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
                    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.partners.signUpVerifyEmailPage</Item>
                    <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
                    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsTransformationStringsAreNotEqual">A user with this email address already exists.</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <InputClaimsTransformations>
                    <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="GetLocalizedStringsForEmail" />
                </InputClaimsTransformations>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OIDC:LoginHint}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                </InputClaims>
                <DisplayClaims>
                    <DisplayClaim DisplayControlReferenceId="localizedSignUpEmailVerificationControl" />
                </DisplayClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                    <!-- this validation asserts the email provided isn't already in use -->
                    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists" />
                </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
                <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
                <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
            </TechnicalProfile>


    <DisplayControl Id="localizedSignUpEmailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </InputClaims>
            <DisplayClaims>
                <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
                <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />                    
            </DisplayClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <Actions>
                <Action Id="SendCode">
                    <ValidationClaimsExchange>  
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp"/>
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendLocalizedOtp"/>
                    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
                </Action>
                <Action Id="VerifyCode">
                    <ValidationClaimsExchange>
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
                    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
                </Action>
            </Actions>
        </DisplayControl>
    </DisplayControls>


            <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists">
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <!-- Required claims -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <!-- ensure that the object id isn't already used -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertObjectIdObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual" />
                    <!-- blank the object id, in the case that it was used, so we can let the user change the email and retest -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetObjectIdToNull" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

**My goal is: Upon pressing the 'Send Verification Code' button, validate that the email is not already in use. Then, if the email is in use: put up an error message, don't send an email and don't progress the control.**

I have tried 3 different approaches and none seem to do the job.

**Approach 1: Validate, Error and Stop**

Details:

- At the top of my SendCode ValidationClaimsExchanges add a ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile for AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists
- On the other ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfiles add ContinueOnError="false"

Results:

- Displays an error to the user when using an email already in use
- The control still prompts for sending a code
- However, the other validation steps still execute and an email is still sent.

In this case, it looks like failing the validation and sending an error message is not the same kind of error that the ContinueOnError looks for.

**Approach 2: Evaluate New Claim, Use Precondition**

Details:

- Create a boolean claim emailAlreadyRegistered
- At the top of my SendCode ValidationClaimsExchanges add a ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile for AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists
- In AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists add a CompareClaims claims transformation to set emailAlreadyRegistered = True if the emails match
- Add preconditions to the other ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfiles using ClaimEquals to see if emailAlreadyRegistered is True

Results:

- Displays an error to the user when using an email already in use
- The control still prompts for sending a code
- However, the other validation steps still execute and an email is still sent.

I think in this case the precondition is not seeing the update to the claim (if I set the claim from my PartnerSignUpVerifyEmailPage technical profile then the preconditions seem to respect it).

**Approach 3: Nested Validation Steps**

Details:

- Create a boolean claim emailAlreadyRegistered
- Create a new claims transformation technical profile
- The new profile takes the email as input and uses a claims transformation to set emailAlreadyRegistered in the input claim transformation
- The new technical profile ALSO has 3 validationtechincalprofiles: AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists, GenerateOtp, SendLocalizedOtp
- In SendCode ValidationClaimsExchanges replace all ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfiles for the one new technical profile

Results:

- Does not display the error when the email is in use
- The control proceeds to the code verification step
- No email is sent

In this case it looks like none of the nested validation technical profiles work at all.

**Solution: (Credit: Christian Le Breton)**

- Create a boolean claim emailAlreadyRegistered
- Split AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists into two separate Technical Profiles
- - The first is the same as described without the output transformations
- - The second is a proper ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider technical profile with the two OutputClaimsTransformations described above, plus a third in between them, This transformation sets emailAlreadyRegistered using a CompareClaims transform. This technical profile also outputs the claim emailAlreadyRegistered with DefaultValue = "false"
- At the top of my SendCode ValidationClaimsExchanges add the two new Technical Profiles
- Add preconditions to the other ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfiles using ClaimEquals to see if emailAlreadyRegistered is 'true'

Basically, what I failed to understand was that an AAD Technical Profile can't set new claims into the bag (I suppose) and a Claims Technical Profile can't read AAD, so these two activities needed to be separated, once I did that the 2nd approach worked.

Here are some of the tricky bits from the final result.

```
        <DisplayControl Id="localizedSignUpEmailVerificationControl" UserInterfaceControlType="VerificationControl">
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </InputClaims>
            <DisplayClaims>
                <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
                <DisplayClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="verificationCode" ControlClaimType="VerificationCode" Required="true" />
            </DisplayClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <Actions>
                <Action Id="SendCode">
                    <ValidationClaimsExchange>
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists-Pt1" ContinueOnError="false" />
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists-Pt2" ContinueOnError="false" />
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="GenerateOtp" ContinueOnError="false" >
                            <Preconditions>
                                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                                    <Value>emailAlreadyRegistered</Value>
                                    <Value>true</Value>
                                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                                </Precondition>
                            </Preconditions>
                        </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SendLocalizedOtp" ContinueOnError="false">
                            <Preconditions>
                                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                                    <Value>emailAlreadyRegistered</Value>
                                    <Value>true</Value>
                                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                                </Precondition>
                            </Preconditions>
                        </ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile>
                    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
                </Action>
                <Action Id="VerifyCode">
                    <ValidationClaimsExchange>
                        <ValidationClaimsExchangeTechnicalProfile TechnicalProfileReferenceId="VerifyOtp" />
                    </ValidationClaimsExchange>
                </Action>
            </Actions>
        </DisplayControl>
                    
        
            <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists-Pt1">
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <!-- Required claims -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" DefaultValue="NOTFOUND" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <!-- ensure that the object id isn't already used -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertObjectIdObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
            </TechnicalProfile>             
            
            <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress-RaiseIfExists-Pt2">
                <DisplayName>Check If Email Is Registered</DisplayName>
                <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">false</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdNotFound" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="emailAlreadyRegistered" />
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
                </OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <!-- ensure that the object id isn't already used -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetEmailAlreadyRegistered" />
                    <!-- blank the object id, in the case that it was used, so we can let the user change the emamil and retest -->
                    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetObjectIdToNull" />
                </OutputClaimsTransformations>
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Hi @fie0x,

I have the similar need. Since you were able to crack it, would it be possible to share the sample policy? I know it was a while back but it could save me a lot of effort. PS: I am very new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DaljitKumar appended some of the tricky bits to my post.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response @fei0x. As I mentioned I am very new to this and trying to decode it. :)

My understanding is that DisplayControl goes in the extension file and Technical Profiles in the base file. Can you pls confirm and specify the location for these snippets.

Comment: @DaljitKumar that stuff is all a rough guideline, it all depends on what pieces you decide to reuse. I almost recommend just doing it all in one file while you're learning, and then decide for yourself how to break it down later.

Comment: @DaljitKumar my biggest tip to a newcomer is to remember that the order of every tag matters, if something doesn't work, just make sure the order of the tags is the same order as the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think approach 1 is likely your best approach, with some slight modifications. The main issue is that claims transformations need to be called from a ClaimsTransformations technical profile that is a validation technical profile, not by calling the ClaimsTransformations profile from within a validation technical profile.

Instead of trying to do everything in one step, it should be broken up into a few steps.

Have your user read technical profile just output the objectId and objectIdNotFound, without the claims transformation, and have your send code step use the read technical profile, the assert technical profile and the set to null technical profile as verification profiles in that order, prior to generating or sending the OTP.

Comment: You didn't mention the display control in your response so I'm a little confused. In your solution how are GenerateOtp and SendLocalizedOtp not executed if the email already exists? Thank you.

Comment: Oops, sorry I missed that and thought you were asking something else,

The validation claims exchange can be any old technical profile, so if you move your validation technical profiles as the first validation claims exchanges under the SendCode step, they will be executed before generating or sending the code. You will likely still need to move the output transformations into their own verification step as well after that one

Edit: I've edited my original response to better reflect my new understanding

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I am misunderstanding something. AssertObjectIdObjectIdNotFoundAreEqual and SetObjectIdToNull are claims transformations not technical profiles, so I can't add them to the validation technical profiles on SendLocalizedOtp. Also, validation technical profiles are executed after the REST call so I don't see how adding them to the SendLocalizedOtp technical profile would stop the email from sending. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles#technical-profile-flow

Comment: Put them in a [Claims Transformation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) also, the validation technical profiles are what are making the REST call. The SendLocalizedOTP validation profile in your display control should be where the API is called

Comment: okay, after a while of trying to sort through this i see what you mean. I got it working with Option 2, but instead of adding JUST user-read I split it into two. I didn't understand that the AAD Read and the Claim creation can't happen in the same TP as you were pointing out. Thank you!